# Firefox on openSUSE 15.1, 15.2 and 15.3 does not load webpages if an internet connection was established after the browser was launched

Tags: networking, opensuse, firefox

On my notebook with openSUSE 15.1, Firefox (version 78.1) does not load new webpages if an internet connection was established *after* launching the browser. If I launch the browser before creating an internet connection, I need to close and restart it before new pages are loaded.

It does not matter whether the internet connection relies on a network cable (which I use at work) or on Wifi (elsewhere). Other browsers I have installed for comparison (SeaMonkey, Otter Browser) do not have this issue, so I am convinced the issue is in Firefox. The issue is not due to accidentally putting the browser in offline mode. I tried checking the settings under `about:config` but I could not find any issues, especially because it is not clear where to start looking in the first place.

Does anybody know how this issue can be solved? I have not experienced this on any other Linux distribution I have used in the past (Fedora, Ubuntu, Manjaro, MX Linux).

**Update (20.10.2020)**: Since posting this question, I have run a distribution upgrade to openSUSE 15.2 and this has not solved the issue. (The current Firefox version on that PC is now - on 30.10.2020 - 78.4.0esr.)

**Update (10.11.2020)**: The issue also occurs when the internet connection was temporarily lost and needs to be re-established. Without restarting Firefox, new pages will not load.

**Update (16.03.2021)**: My Firefox version is now 78.8.0esr and the issue is still present.

**Update (25.07.2022)**: After upgrading to OpenSUSE Leap 15.3, I have noticed that the issue also affects Chromium.

Comment: I have the same issue!

Comment: @sivic On which openSUSE version(s)?

Comment: Yeah same here, at least sometimes. I haven't tried it that way in a while. I'm currently running Leap 15.2. Hm, I just retried and now it worked... Firefox version 81.0.1

Comment: @eblock After updating the system, I have Firefox 78.3.0esr, not 81.0.1.

Comment: @Tsundoku apparently I have a different repo, I'll check later.

Comment: Confirmed, I don't use the default repos (https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/mozilla/openSUSE_Leap_15.2/) for firefox, but I can't downgrade right now to test.

Comment: @Tsundoku Its openSUSE Leap 15.1, but I think it is solved in some update since I didn't encountered this issue in last couple of weeks.

Comment: @sivic As I wrote in my update from 20 October, I updated the PC to openSUSE 15.2 and the problem still persists.

Comment: With firefox: try in `about:config` setting `network.manage-offline-status` to `false`

Comment: @stoney Thanks. Unfortunately, that did not turn out to be the solution.